# Getting the count of sheets in debug mode - MS Excel PIA

Tags: vb.net, excel, debugging, interop, excel-interop

I cannot access `.Count` property of `Sheets`. I'm using Excel Interop. I'm in debug mode and I'm trying this:

```
?xlSheets.Count
```

This results in:

> (1) : error BC30456: 'Count' is not a member of 'Sheets'.

I have no clue on what's wrong, as [I see in MSDN that there is such property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sheets.count.aspx)!

This works well: `?xlSheets(1).Name`. But `Count` fails... Is it possible to get the count of sheets?

[These guys had a similar problem](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?502029-Using-vb-net-to-add-a-new-sheet-in-excel) - they wanted to `.Worksheets.Add(.Worksheets.Sheets.Count)`. Finally *they did not get the count*, they went for `.Worksheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets(3))`...

---

UPDATE:

To my great delight, after further trying / experimentations, it became clear that **in debug mode`Sheets.Count` does not work *only* when there is no such line in the code**.

While debugging this code, I can access `Sheets.Count`, because this line exists in the code.

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkbooks As Excel.Workbooks
    Dim xlSheets As Excel.Sheets

    Private Sub btnCreate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click
        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlWorkbooks = xlApp.Workbooks
        xlWorkBook = xlWorkbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Template.xlsm")
        xlSheets = xlWorkBook.Sheets

        MessageBox.Show(xlSheets.Count)

        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()

        'Clean Up
        releaseObject(xlSheets)
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
        releaseObject(xlWorkbooks)
        releaseObject(xlApp)
    End Sub

    Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
            obj = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            obj = Nothing
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

But when I replace `MessageBox.Show(xlSheets.Count)` with `MessageBox.Show(xlSheets.Creator)`, the error appears when trying to `?xlSheets.Count`. I don't yet know the reason of such behaviour (I come from VBA environment where debug mode seems to be more flexible), but at least that works during run time...

If someone knows how to fix this, please let me know, as *I feel restricted* while testing small things in debug mode!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Project > Properties > References.  Locate and select the "Microsoft Excel xx.x Object Library" entry.  In the Properties window, set the Embed Interop Types property to False.  Use Build > Rebuild to rebuild your app.  It will now work the way you expected.

Briefly, this option is a strong optimization for COM interop libraries, like Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, you no longer have a runtime dependency on the library.  The compiler copies the interop types from the library into your program's executable, only the ones you actually need to run your program.  Explains your discovery, the Count property is in fact missing when you don't use it in your program.

You don't want to leave it this way, set the property back to True after you're done testing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. I notice the file type is a macro-enabled workbook. Have you set your macro settings properly on your dev PC? By default Excel will disable macros.

Edit: I think I get your problem now. You are getting the error when trying to print the property in debug mode. Probably you have stopped the code at a point where the variable is not set (.Count is only available while the button code is actually running). Put a breakpoint on the message box line, click the button, and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Everything is fine with macro settings, I use them a lot, so I think I have the necessary things enabled. I have further tested the case and updated the question for better chances of reproducing the issue.

Comment: In VBA the spreadsheet is always in memory. In .NET you have to load it and unload it :-)

Comment: At that point the variable was set already. I am sure VBA would also produce the same error if I tried to access properties of the variable when it's not set.